# map a string list in sqlserver like listagg

Tags: sql, sql-server

i try conver some string such as '1,2,3' to 'a,b,c' with the anwser:

```
    select stuff(
    (
      select ',' + realname from sys_user
      where ','+'1,2,3'+',' like '%,'+cast(u_id as varchar(10))+',%' for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'')
```

`charindex` is well done. but i want to create a more common function, so that i can convert in any relation such that.

i try a function :

```
create function [dbo].[fn_enum2str]
(
  @enum as varchar(1000),
  @table_name as varchar(100),
  @origin_field as varchar(100),
  @target_field as varchar(100)
)
as
begin
  declare @result varchar(1000)
  declare @sqlstr nvarchar(1000)

  set @sqlstr = 'set @result = ('
  set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + 'select stuff('
  set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + '(select '','' + ' +@target_field+ ' from ' + @table_name
  set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' where '','+@enum+','' like ''%,''+cast('+@origin_field+' as varchar)+'',%'' for xml path(''''))'
  set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ',1,1,''''))'

  exec(@sqlstr)
  return @result
end
```

it faild with error, as you know, it is not allow to exec a dynamic sql in function.

i want to

```
select dbo.fn_enum2str(a.uids,'sys_user','u_id', 'realname') from my_table a
--output 'a,b,c'
```

so, in my question, how can i create a function or a proc to deal it ?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is used?

Comment: sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have SQL-SERVER2016 you can use string_split like this:

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stringlist]([Numbers] [nvarchar](50) NULL) 
Insert into dbo.Stringlist(numbers)
values('1,2,3,4,5,10')
```

**SQL Function**

```
 alter function dbo.HinkyBase26( @Value as varchar(250) ) returns VarChar(250) as
  begin


 --declare @Value as varchar(50) = '13,14,1,2,5,14'
  -- Notes: 'A' = 0.  Negative numbers are not handled.
  declare @Result as VarChar(250) = '';

 declare @stringsplit table (numbers nvarchar(50),Letters varchar(1))

insert into @stringsplit(numbers,Letters)
  select numbers = @Value ,CHAR(64 + value) as Letters from string_split(@Value,',')

  select @Result = Letter from (
  select numbers,Letter = STUFF((Select  ', ' + Letters
  from @stringsplit b
  where b.numbers = a.numbers 
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
  from @stringsplit a
  group by numbers
  )z



  return @Result

end
```

**Execution of function**

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Numbers],dbo.HinkyBase26(Numbers)
  FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[stringlist]
```

[image]

**SQL Stored Proc**

```
Create PROC dbo.usp_convertnumberstostring

@stringvalue nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN


Create table #stringsplit (numbers nvarchar(50),Letters varchar(1))

insert into #stringsplit(numbers,Letters)
SELECT Numbers = @stringvalue,CHAR(64 + value) as Letters

 from string_split(@stringvalue,',')

  select numbers,Letter = STUFF((Select DISTINCT ', ' + Letters
  from #stringsplit b
  where b.numbers = a.numbers 
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
  from #stringsplit a
  group by numbers
  drop table #stringsplit
  END
```

**Execute SP**

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @stringvalue nvarchar(250) = '1,5,6'

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

    EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[usp_convertnumberstostring] 
       @stringvalue
    GO
```

**Result**

[image]

**SQL Script**

```
    Create table #stringsplit (numbers nvarchar(50),Letters varchar(1))

insert into #stringsplit(numbers,Letters)
SELECT Numbers,CHAR(64 + value) as Letters
  FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[stringlist] a
  cross apply string_split(numbers,',')

  select numbers,Letter = STUFF((Select DISTINCT ', ' + Letters
  from #stringsplit b
  where b.numbers = a.numbers 
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
  from #stringsplit a
  group by numbers

Drop table #stringsplit
```

Comment: thanks your anwser.  but only want to use it in a DML env,  such as `select dbo.fn_enum2str(a.uids,'sys_user','u_id', 'realname') from my_table a`,  that the `table_name` and 'field' name is dynamic input, so i can use in different business table relation.

Comment: So you want a function which can be used on your select statements?

Comment: yes,  every time i write a select sql like this , i would to write the grammar of `stuff` and `for xm path`， it is repeat in many business sql. it lead to my sql is long and difficult to read.  if in oracle , listagg is troublesome also.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  but it can not deal my question.  i need a function can input a table name and table's colunm to concat it to a string like  'a,b,c'， in your anwser, the table is fixed.   now , i have try a function use `if` to decide which table to use,  such as `if @table_name= 'sys_user' set @result= stuff......realname from sys_user  if @table_name=sys_attachment set @result=stuff...filepath from sys_attachment`

Comment: The function is called upon the table you use. You cannot use another table. That makes no sense. Anyways, this should get you started. Simple just edit the function to take the required parameters

Comment: I had paste my anwser, manage with an effort.  thanks your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_enum2str]
(
  @enum as varchar(1000),
  @table_name as varchar(100)
)
returns varchar(1000)
as
begin
  declare @result varchar(1000)

  if @enum is null
    return ''

  if @table_name = 'sys_user'
    set @result = (
      select stuff(
        (
          select ',' + realname from sys_user
          where ','+@enum+',' like '%,'+cast(u_id as varchar(10))+',%' for xml path('')
        ),1,1,''
      )
    )
  if @table_name = 'sys_attachment'
    set @result = (
      select stuff(
        (
          select ',/' + filepath from sys_attachment
          where ','+@enum+',' like '%,'+cast(aid as varchar(10))+',%' for xml path('')
        ),1,1,''
      )
    )
  return @result
end
GO
```

only way to deal it what i can think of, to switch which sql will be exec by a flag.  when other relation apearance, add it to the switch list.

```
select 
    dbo.fn_enum2str(a.uids, 'sys_user') as names,
    dbo.fn_enum2str(a.attachids, 'sys_attachment') as filepaths
from my_table a
```

so that it can be overlay. yes, it is difficult to remember `stuff` or `for xml path` or `listagg(oracle)`, and result to a long sql, and i am lazy.

if you have any anwser better, tell me, thanks.